# How to use different field as label for modelformset?

Tags: python, django

I'm creating an inventory management system using django as a framework. I have a simple model with a product column and an order_amount column. The only part I want users being able to update using the modelformset is the order_amount column. Django automatically labels each form with the field name "Order Amount". What I would like it to do is to label each form as the instance it is updating from the Product field.

models.py

```
class Sysco_Products(models.Model):
    Products = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    order_amount = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Products

    class meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'sysco_products'
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Sysco_Products

class orderform(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Sysco_Products
        fields = ('order_amount',)
```

views.py

```
class SyscoOrder(TemplateView):
        template_name= "SyscoOrder.html"

        def get(self, request):
                OrderFormSet = modelformset_factory(Sysco_Products, fields=('order_amount',))
                context = {
                        'OrderFormSet' : OrderFormSet,
                }
                return render(request, self.template_name, context)

        def post(self, request):
                OrderFormSet = modelformset_factory(Sysco_Products, fields=('order_amount',))
                formset = OrderFormSet(request.POST,)
                if formset.is_valid():
                        formset.save()
                        return redirect('Order')

                context ={
                        'formset' : formset,
                }
                return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like `field.label = f"{sysco_product_instance.Products} amount:"`?

This should work:

```py
from django.utils.translation import gettext

class orderform(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Sysco_Products
        fields = ('order_amount',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(self, orderform).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance.Products.strip():
            self.fields['order_amount'].label = gettext("%(product_name)s amount:").format(product_name=self.instance.Products)
```